# How to find the second moment for a multivariate gaussian

Tags: probability, statistics

> I am trying to check how $\mathbb{E}\|X\|^2$ scales with $d$ where $X\in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a random variable whose distribution is $p(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)^{d/2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2}$ ($\|\cdot\|$ is the euclidean distance).

$$\mathbb{E}\|X\|^2=\mathbb{E}\sum_{i=1}^d X_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^d \mathbb{E}X_i^2$$

where $X_i$ is the $i-$th component of $X$ but I am not sure how to find $\mathbb{E}X_i^2$. Any ideas?

Comment: That is not a multivariate Gaussian density. And how is that even a valid density, i.e. how does that integrate to 1?

Comment: A standard normal has density $f(x)=(2\pi)^{-d/2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2}.$ Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio You are right, its a typo, corrected that now.

Comment: I corrected the exponent too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $X$ is standard multivariate normal, i.e. it has density

$$f(x)=(2\pi)^{-d/2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2},$$

then each component $X_i$  is iid $N(0,1)$.

Thus, $$E[\|X\|^2]=\sum_{i=1}^d E[X_i^2]=\sum_{i=1}^d 1=d.$$